# Print bind variables when using execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm trying to print out the vSQL variable after the execute immediate statement.
i know the execute immediate statement ll give ORA-00903 because u can not bind variables to tables etc.i just want to print that string after using
statement.

here is my code :

```
DECLARE 
vSQL VARCHAR2(100);
vOwner VARCHAR2(100);
vTableName VARCHAR2(100);
vPartition VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    vOwner := 'STG';
    vTableName := 'TEMP';
    vSQL := 'ALTER TABLE :1.:2 TRUNCATE PARTITION(:3)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL USING vOwner,vTableName,vPartition;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vSQL); -- Something like this
END;
```

thx for ideas...

Comment: It's not allowed to bind identifiers. If you simply want to *print* that `alter table` statement why is the `execute immediate` statement there? It won't ever be successfully executed anyway unless you drop the idea of trying to bind identifiers.

Comment: Bind variable cant be use to set schema objects! Form a string instead, no other way!

Comment: In your case, vSQL never gets modified when you run it along with the bind variable, if you think that **:1 will be replaced with vOwner value, it is not possible**. Oracle do all the substitutions during execution time.

Comment: so is it possible to trace the substitutions during execution time ?

Answer (score 3):

As the commenters wrote you can bind only data to fields, you can't bind library object's names/etc.

So I think you can do it only without binding:

```
DECLARE 
vSQL VARCHAR2(100);
vOwner VARCHAR2(100);
vTableName VARCHAR2(100);
vPartition VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    vOwner := 'STG';
    vTableName := 'TEMP';
    vSQL := 'ALTER TABLE ' || vOwner || '.' || vTableName || ' TRUNCATE PARTITION('||vPartition||')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vSQL);
END;
```

Comment: You get my question wrong ,  i already know how to work the query in a proper way. I just wanted to know how can i trace(debug) the code when it fails like my code.

Comment: I don't understand 100%. This substitution won't ever happen. If this is only a fake example for something what could happen then maybe some kind of tracing could help and you could extract from the related udump/etc files what happened internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you know an error is going to happen, catch it and then print.

```
DECLARE 
vSQL VARCHAR2(100);
vOwner VARCHAR2(100);
vTableName VARCHAR2(100);
vPartition VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    vOwner := 'STG';
    vTableName := 'TEMP';
    vSQL := 'ALTER TABLE :1.:2 TRUNCATE PARTITION(:3)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL USING vOwner,vTableName,vPartition;

    EXCEPTION   --The error will get catched here.     
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vSQL); --This will print exactly 'ALTER TABLE :1.:2 TRUNCATE PARTITION(:3)'
           --If you want to print it with the variables do something like:
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ALTER TABLE ' || vOwner || ', ' || vTableName || ', ' || vPartition; 

END;
```